# How can I stop the program inside the a parent or a child process?

Tags: process, fork, kill, fflush

I have this piece of code that I developed just to address a problem that I have in another large program that I am developing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void processLine (char []);
void readLine(char []);

const int LIMIT = 512;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char oneLine[LINE_MAX];
    readLine(oneLine);
    
        
    return 0;
}
void readLine(char line[])
{
    processLine(line);
    

 //Otherstuff
 ------------

}
void processLine(char line[])
{
    
    pid_t process;
    int child_status;

    string input;
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input;

    
        process = fork();
        if(process == 0)
        { // do nothing
        }
        else 
        {
                        //parent
                    if(input == "quit")
            {
                printf("Quit command found ! \nExiting ");
                    
                for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
                {
                    printf(".");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    sleep(1);
                    
                }
            
                printf("\n");
                    exit(0);            
            }
            else
            {
                wait(&child_status);
            }
        }
    
}
```

My goal is simple, When the user enter quit.

I will just display

> Quit command found
>
> Exiting **...**

And there is a delay of one second between each of these three dots.

However the output that I get is

> Quit command found
>
> Exiting **. other stuff ..**

However, what seems to happen is that the parent process returns and then executes other stuff from the calling function before it continues to print the other two dots. How  would I avoid the parent process from doing that ?

Comment: @Olaf This is mainly c

Comment: And artificial delays in a program are always cause of irritation an aggravate the user.

Comment: I'd say (in case the user entered "*quit*") the **child** "*returns and then executes other stuff from the calling function*".

Comment: It's the child process that prints the `other stuff`: the return of `fork` is `0` for the child, your `// do nothing`, which then exists `processLine`, continuing to do `other stuff`.

Comment: "This is mainly c"  which makes it badly codes C++, but still not C! Similar syntax does not imply same semantics. Unless it compiles with a C compiler, it is not C.

Comment: @Kenney How would the child process from doing that when the user enters quit ?

Comment: You can't, really. It behaves in the way you wrote it: you first enter "quit", *then* you fork the child, *then* you wait for 3 seconds (and let the child run for 3 seconds doing it's stuff), and only *then* you exit. Perhaps what you intend is something like this: first `fork`, then loop over `stdin` (in the parent) until you get a `quit`, and then immediately call exit.

Comment: @Kenney I fixed it, I basically check again in the child if the input is quit and I exit in this case !!

Answer (score 0):

Use waitpid() like this:

```
pid_t childPid;  
childPid = fork();
...
int returnStatus;    
waitpid(childPid, &returnStatus, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.
```

Use it here

```
if(childPid == 0)  // fork succeeded 
{   
   // Do something   
   exit(0); 
}
else  // Main (parent) process after fork succeeds 
{    
    int returnStatus;    
    waitpid(childPid, &returnStatus, 0);
}
```

Comment: where should  I do this wait ?

Comment: in main process , after fork